# PHP converting simple array to more complex associative array

Tags: php, arrays

My selection from DB returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bin_full] => AA010101
            [letter1_zone] => A
            [letter2_aisle] => A
            [letter34_bay] => 01
            [letter56_level] => 01
            [letter78_bin] => 01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bin_full] => AA010102
            [letter1_zone] => A
            [letter2_aisle] => A
            [letter34_bay] => 01
            [letter56_level] => 01
            [letter78_bin] => 02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bin_full] => AA010201
            [letter1_zone] => A
            [letter2_aisle] => A
            [letter34_bay] => 01
            [letter56_level] => 02
            [letter78_bin] => 01
        )
```

As you can see, its basically the first item bin_full, being broken up into first letter, second letter, then next 2 numbers, next 2 numbers and finally the last 2 numbers. The pattern is the same, I need each level grouped together in an assoc array.

If I then do this, I'm mostly getting the result I want, but it needs a tweak and I'm not sure how to do that..

```
foreach ($data_full as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key2 => $value2) {
        $data_array[$row['letter1_zone']][$row['letter2_aisle']][$row['letter34_bay']][$row['letter56_level']][$row['letter78_bin']] = $value2;
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [A] => Array
                (
                    [01] => Array
                        (
                            [01] => Array
                                (
                                    [01] => 01
                                    [02] => 02
                                )

                            [02] => Array
                                (
                                    [01] => 01
                                    [02] => 02
                                )

                            [03] => Array
                                (
                                    [01] => 01
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I need the last array to be:

```
[0] => 01
[1] => 02
```

not

```
[01] => 01
[02] => 02
```

In full, I need this:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [A] => Array
                (
                    [01] => Array
                        (
                            [01] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 01
                                    [1] => 02
                                )

                            [02] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 01
                                    [1] => 02
                                )

                            [03] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 01
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is replace this :

```
foreach ($data_full as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key2 => $value2) {
        $data_array[$row['letter1_zone']][$row['letter2_aisle']][$row['letter34_bay']][$row['letter56_level']][$row['letter78_bin']] = $value2;
    }
}
```

with this :

```
foreach ($data_full as $row) {
    $data_array[$row['letter1_zone']][$row['letter2_aisle']][$row['letter34_bay']][$row['letter56_level']][] = $row['letter78_bin'];
}
```

so you replace the last index with a "add new element": []. It will first add index 0, then 1, then 2, etc...

Comment: This returns:
[0] => AA010101
                                    [1] => A
                                    [2] => A
                                    [3] => 01
                                    [4] => 01
                                    [5] => 01
                                    [6] => AA010102
                                    [7] => A
                                    [8] => A
                                    [9] => 01
                                    [10] => 01
                                    [11] => 02

Comment: [] this would always start the index from zero, but what is understand from questions is, the index the coming from existing array, and it could be anything.

Comment: Indeed, the "value2" at the end is not relevent, as the 2nd loop does. try this (edited answer)

Answer (score -1):

```
    $data_array[$row['letter1_zone']][$row['letter2_aisle']][$row['letter34_bay']][$row['letter56_level']][] = $value2;
```

Comment: This returns: [1] => 01
                                    [2] => 02

ie: it starts at 1 not 0

Comment: As i understand [letter78_bin] value is coming from database, and it would become the key of the array, so its better to use intval so that index doesn't start from the zero.

Comment: @mitkosoft - No, i understand if index needs to start from zero [] can be used, but here if my understanding is correct, Mark whats to convert the value received from database into key format, and wants to covert 01 to 1...

Comment: Sorry guyz, understood the question correctly, my bad. [] would work.

Comment: inval-1 would give me the result I'm looking for, but thats not really the right way to do it, is it?

Comment: @Mark - Random's solution would work, i have edited my answer based on the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Peeje , your first suggestion was much closer to the result I was looking for.